# How to decide which Encoder to use for which language in Elasticsearch "Phonetic Token filter"?

Tags: elasticsearch, phonetics, metaphone

I have used **Metaphone** and **soundex** Encoder with "Phonetic Token Filter" in Elasticsearch.

**Metaphone** is good for English words.

**Soundex** is good for *English* as well as *Hindi* maybe many *other languages* as well.

I want to know which of these encoders is best optimized for Hindi and if possible other Indian languages?

- Soundex
- Metaphone
- double_metaphone
- refined_soundex
- caverphone1 - English (New Zealand localised)
- caverphone2 -  English (New Zealand localised)
- cologne - German
- nysiis - Improvized Soundex
- koelnerphonetik - German
- haasephonetik - German
- beider_morse - English and multiple European Language
- daitch_mokotoff - Slavic & Yiddish Surname

As This is not listed on [Elasticsearch website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-phonetic-token-filter.html) for which Language we should choose which Encoder.

Also tell me which of the Encoders have you already used and for which language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phonetic encoders are alogorithms for indexing words by their pronunciation.

Explanation for this is available on wikipedia

> 1. **Metaphone, Double Metaphone, and Metaphone 3** : suitable for use with most English words, not just names. Metaphone algorithms are
>      the basis for many popular spell checkers. The Double Metaphone
>      phonetic encoding algorithm is the second generation of this
>      algorithm.
> 2. **Soundex**: which was developed to encode surnames for use in censuses. Soundex codes are four-character strings composed of a
>      single letter followed by three numbers.
> 3. **Daitch–Mokotoff Soundex**: which is a refinement of Soundex designed to better match surnames of Slavic and Germanic origin.
>      Daitch–Mokotoff Soundex codes are strings composed of six numeric
>      digits.
> 4. **Cologne phonetics** :This is similar to Soundex, but more suitable for German words.
> 5. **New York State Identification and Intelligence System (NYSIIS)**: which maps similar phonemes to the same letter. The result
>      is a string that can be pronounced by the reader without decoding.
> 6. **Match Rating Approach developed by Western Airlines in 1977**: this algorithm has an encoding and range comparison technique.
> 7. **Caverphone**: created to assist in data matching between late 19th century and early 20th century electoral rolls, optimized for
>      accents present in parts of New Zealand

References:
    Details of above algorithms and their subtypes us available in below wikipedia page
 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm

Among above SoundEx is most suitable for Indian languages
You can check below resources for same
1. [Phonetic search for Indian languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843475/phonetic-search-for-indian-languages)
2. https://thottingal.in/blog/2009/07/26/indicsoundex/